# Python - split string with multiple delimiters, return dictionary delimiter as key remaining item as value

Tags: python, dictionary, split

So I wanted to know if there was something out there that took a string, split it over multiple delimiters, but instead of returning a list, it returned a dictionary of what delimiter was used to split the string, followed by the unsplit string up to the next delimiter. For example, consider this list:

```
Food to make:

1. Cake
    a. eggs
    b. flour
    c. milk
    d. etc
2. Salad
    a. lettuce
    b. spinach
    c. cheese
    d. ham
    e. etc
```

Here is the list unformatted:

```
GroceryList = "1. Cake a. eggs b. flour c. milk d. etc 2. Salad a. lettuce b. spinach c. cheese d. ham e. etc"
```

When I run my script, I need it to split over alphanumeric values (and the period), then return it as a dictionary. Ideally, I would like to be able to set the dilemeters by the use of a list (`my_str = "123test123" my_str.split(["1", "3"])` to split the string over values "1" and "3", returning a dict of `{"1#1": "2", "3#1": "test", "1#2": "2", "3#2": ""}`). I understand any repeats would be overwritten in the dictionary so it'd have to have a unique ID associated with it like so:

```
{"#1": "Food to make:",
"1.#1": "Cake",
"a.#1": "eggs",
"b.#1": "flour",
"c.#1": "milk",
"d.#1": "etc",
"2.#2": "Salad",
"a.#2": "lettuce",
"b.#2": "spinach",
"c.#2": "cheese",
"d.#2": "ham",
"e.#2": "etc"}
```

I wouldn't think that there would be a native function to do this, but seeing I am not real familiar with python (I'm running python 3.8), I figured I give the question a shot.

I've looked at mapping and lambda functions as an alternative to try and achieve this goal, but I wouldn't know where to even begin tackling a problem like this, so if there is something native to accomplish this task, then that would be best.

Thank you!

---Edit From Some Time Later---
In retrospect, I can see how this might be confusing, so in an effort to clarify, here is example input that I will actually be dealing with:

```
M 10 315
L 110 215
A 30 50 0 0 1 162.55 162.45
L 172.55 152.45
A 30 50 -45 0 1 215.1 109.9
L 315 10
```

and because the data identifiers need to be unique, I don't care so much as to how the data is stored, but rather that it stays unique. Lists are sorted in the order added by default, so I settled on that idea in my answer.

Comment: is your input "list" a text file or something?

Comment: Can you post your exact input as a variable that can be reproduced by others on their machines?

Comment: Yah, its a string created from a different object

Comment: @AkshaySehgal try that out... I can just see sooooo much parsing in my future

Comment: No thats not what i mean. The `Food to make:

1. Cake
    a. eggs
    b. flour
    c. milk
    d. etc
`

Comment: what is the variable that holds that?

Comment: can you `print(var)` and copy paste the ouptut

Comment: `"#1": "Food to make:"` Why exactly is `"Food to make:"` included in `"#1"`??

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Now that I wrote it as a variable does it make sense? The first part doesn't hit a dilimeter, but it will eventually hit the `1.` which is a dilimeter.

Comment: @ShanerM13 Never mind, I get it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 so would you suggest getting rid of the text that wasn't split over a dilimeter? Okay. cool.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal, the "grocery list" can be copied and pasted into a file, opened and you will get the same output that you need. Just remove the `"""`

Comment: @ShanerM13 Give it a try, then ask a more specific question about what isn't working. Print out the results of splitting, set some variables, and you should understand what to do pretty well. If not, ask a specific question about a specific part you don't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage:

1. Save the class as a file... I called mine StringSplitter.py.
2. `import StringSplitter as SS`
3. `ss = SS.StringSplitter("123test123", ["1", "3"])`
4. `ss.split()` computes and returns the output
5. `ss.toFile("./split.txt")` to write to a file called "split.txt".

Which returns:
`[{'delimiter': '1', 'start': 0, 'end': 1, 'content': '2'}, {'delimiter': '3', 'start': 2, 'end': 3, 'content': 'testing'}, {'delimiter': '1', 'start': 10, 'end': 11, 'content': '2'}, {'delimiter': '3', 'start': 12, 'end': 13, 'content': ''}]`

When you reconstruct the string with the pattern delimiter + content, it yields:
`123testing123`

```
class StringSplitter:
    def __init__(self, string=None, delimiter=None, caseSensitive=True):
        self.string = string
        self.splitted = []
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.caseSensitive = caseSensitive
        self.split()
        self.rmDupeStr = ""

    def toFile(self, path):
        with open(path, "w") as file:
            file.writelines(str(self.splitted))

    def split(self):
        i = 0
        delCount = len(self.delimiter)
        strLen = len(self.string)
        split = []

        #loop through all chars in string
        while i < strLen:
            j = 0
            #loop over all possible delimiters
            while j < delCount:
                #get the delimiters
                searchitem = self.delimiter[j]
                compChar = self.string[i]
                if self.caseSensitive != True:
                    searchitem = searchitem.lower()
                    compChar = compChar.lower()
                #if the delimiter at its char 0 is the same as the string at i
                if searchitem[0] == compChar:
                    compItem = self.string[i:i + len(searchitem)]
                    if self.caseSensitive != True:
                        compItem = compItem.lower()
                    #check to see if the whole delimiter is matched at the rest of the string starting at i
                    if compItem == searchitem:
                        searchitem = self.string[i:i + len(searchitem)]
                        #then if there wasn't a match at the first character when a match was found,
                        #take the stuff up to the first match and make a dict out of it
                        #example: "string", ["i"] => [{"": "str"},{"i": "ng"}]
                        #for the purpose of this project, this is probably unnecessary
                        if len(split) == 0 and i > 0:
                            split.append({"delimiter": "", "start": 0, "end": i, "content": self.string[0: i]})
                            split.append({"delimiter": searchitem, "start": i, "end": i + len(searchitem), "content": ""})
                        else:
                            #add the delimiter and the starting and ending location of the of the delimiter
                            if len(split) > 0:
                                split[-1]["content"] = self.string[split[-1]["end"]: i]
                            split.append({"delimiter": searchitem, "start": i, "end": i + len(searchitem), "content": ""})
                        #break the loop
                        j = delCount + 1
                        #if len(split) > 1:
                        #    split[-2]["content"] = self.string[int(split[-2]["end"]):int(split[-1]["start"])]
                    else:
                        #keep searching
                        j += 1
                else:
                    #keep searching
                    j += 1
            #keep searching
            i += 1

        if len(split) > 1:
            split[-1]["content"] = self.string[int(split[-1]["end"]):]
        elif len(split) == 1:
            split[0]["content"] = self.string[int(split[0]["end"]):]
        else:
            split.append({"delimiter": "", "start": 0, "end": strLen, "content": self.string})
        self.splitted = split
        return split

    def rmDupe(self):
        self.rmDupeStr = ""
        prevcontent = None
        prevdelimiter = None
        for i in range(len(self.splitted)):
            content = self.splitted[i]["content"]
            delimiter = self.splitted[i]["delimiter"]
            if i > 0:
                if prevdelimiter == delimiter:
                    # if prevcontent == content:
                    # then don't add them together, ex: "ssssss", so we are left with:
                    if prevcontent != content:
                        self.rmDupeStr += delimiter + content
                else:
                    self.rmDupeStr += delimiter + content

            else:
                self.rmDupeStr += delimiter + content
            prevcontent = content
            prevdelimiter = delimiter
        return self.rmDupeStr
```

---

Sample data from post:

```
import StringSplitter as SS
a = "M 10 315 L 110 215 A 30 50 0 0 1 162.55 162.45 L 172.55 152.45 A 30 50 -45 0 1 215.1 109.9 L 315 10"
ss = SS.StringSplitter(a, ["M", "L,", "A", " "])
ss.split()
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'delimiter': 'M', 'start': 0, 'end': 1, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 1, 'end': 2, 'content': '10'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 4, 'end': 5, 'content': '315'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 8, 'end': 9, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': 'L', 'start': 9, 'end': 10, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 10, 'end': 11, 'content': '110'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 14, 'end': 15, 'content': '215'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 18, 'end': 19, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': 'A', 'start': 19, 'end': 20, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 20, 'end': 21, 'content': '30'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 23, 'end': 24, 'content': '50'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 26, 'end': 27, 'content': '0'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 28, 'end': 29, 'content': '0'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 30, 'end': 31, 'content': '1'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 32, 'end': 33, 'content': '162.55'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 39, 'end': 40, 'content': '162.45'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 46, 'end': 47, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': 'L', 'start': 47, 'end': 48, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 48, 'end': 49, 'content': '172.55'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 55, 'end': 56, 'content': '152.45'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 62, 'end': 63, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': 'A', 'start': 63, 'end': 64, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 64, 'end': 65, 'content': '30'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 67, 'end': 68, 'content': '50'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 70, 'end': 71, 'content': '-45'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 74, 'end': 75, 'content': '0'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 76, 'end': 77, 'content': '1'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 78, 'end': 79, 'content': '215.1'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 84, 'end': 85, 'content': '109.9'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 90, 'end': 91, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': 'L', 'start': 91, 'end': 92, 'content': ''}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 92, 'end': 93, 'content': '315'}
{'delimiter': ' ', 'start': 96, 'end': 97, 'content': '10'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
import re
import string

alp = ' '+string.ascii_lowercase

#split by digits and then split by words
items = [re.split('\w\.',i) for i in re.split('\d\.', GroceryList)][1:]

#iterate over list of lists while keeping track of the index with enumerate
#then for the inner index return, return corresponding alphabet
#finally apply dict transformation
result = dict([(alp[l]+'#'+str(i),m.strip()) for i,j in enumerate(items,1) for l,m in enumerate(j)])
result
```

```
{' #1': 'Cake',
 'a#1': 'eggs',
 'b#1': 'flour',
 'c#1': 'milk',
 'd#1': 'etc',
 ' #2': 'Salad',
 'a#2': 'lettuce',
 'b#2': 'spinach',
 'c#2': 'cheese',
 'd#2': 'ham',
 'e#2': 'etc'}
```

Comment: 1. Just want to say that I haven't tested this yet, but I sure do appreciate the help and (what I personally think) to be a very slick solution.
2. `items` is missing a closing bracket.
3. The result isn't exactly what I am going for, but it is a great start. I updated my question (underneath the unformatted string) to talk about how the function should work.
4. Its a good start, I will try to improve this. Thank you!