# how to remove parentheses and all their content inside them

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a word document where I would like to remove the parentheses and their respective content from the beginning and/or end of the paragraph. The problem is that:

1. I would like to avoid using the regex pattern because I noticed that it ended up excluding other elements from the document
2. the paragraphs I'm looking for, the parentheses and their content, must be of a specific style. Or in the standard styles of the Word document or those that begin with a number followed by ) or a letter followed by )
3. The word styles I'm talking about are these: ['List', 'List Paragraph', 'paragraph', 'Normal']

I have a function that checks the document if the paragraph starts with a number followed by ) or letter followed by )
And I also tried to make a code that excluded the parentheses, but without success.
Here is my code:

```
textos_encontrados = []
paragrafos_originais = []
paragrafos_com_padrao = []
paragrafos_sem_padrao = []
estilos_de_paragrafo = ['List', 'List Paragraph', 'paragraph', 'Normal']

lista_range_numeros_letras = [str(c) for c in range(2000)] + [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(26)]
lista_de_simbolos = [')', '.',  'º',  '-',  'ª']
lista_range_de_simbolos = [str(simbolo) for simbolo in lista_de_simbolos]
indice_numeros = 0
primeiro_numero = lista_range_numeros_letras[0]

def verifica_sequencia(paragrafo):
            texto = paragrafo.text
            indice = 0
            sequencia = []

            while indice < len(texto):
                if texto[indice] in lista_range_numeros_letras:
                    sequencia.append(texto[indice])
                    indice += 1
                else:
                    break

            if sequencia:
                for simbolo in lista_de_simbolos:
                    if indice < len(texto) and texto[indice] == simbolo:
                        print("Sequência:", "".join(sequencia))
                        print(f"Próximo elemento é um símbolo: {simbolo}")
                        texto_encontrado = texto.strip()
                        textos_encontrados.append(texto_encontrado)
                        paragrafos_sem_padrao.append(paragrafo.text)
                        print("PARAGRAFOS SEM PADRAO", paragrafos_com_padrao)
                        break

for paragrafo in document.paragraphs:
            verifica_sequencia(paragrafo)
            texto = paragrafo.text
            if paragrafo.style.name in estilos_de_paragrafo:
                texto_encontrado = texto.strip()
                textos_encontrados.append(texto_encontrado)
                paragrafos_com_padrao.append(paragrafo.text)
                print("PARAGRAFOS COM ESTILO:", paragrafos_com_padrao)
        print("TEXTOS ENCONTRADOS", textos_encontrados)

def remove_text_inside_brackets(text, brackets="()[]"):
            count = [0] * (len(brackets) // 2)  # count open/close brackets
            saved_chars = []
            for character in paragrafos_com_padrao:
                for i, b in enumerate(brackets):
                    if character == b:  # found bracket
                        kind, is_close = divmod(i, 2)
                        count[kind] += (-1) ** is_close  # `+1`: open, `-1`: close
                        if count[kind] < 0:  # unbalanced bracket
                            count[kind] = 0  # keep it
                        else:  # found bracket to remove
                            break
                else:  # character is not a [balanced] bracket
                    if not any(count):  # outside brackets
                        saved_chars.append(character)
            return ''.join(saved_chars)
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Correct indentation is crucial for Python.

Comment: Doesn't Word have a style for indexed lists? So I don't think you would actually see the parentheses in the text, you should just look for those paragraph styles.

Comment: @Barmar i did! and this list I sent called estilos_paragrafos contains this

Comment: @Barmar the code indentation is correct. Even though it doesn't seem like it here

Comment: I don't care if it's correct there, make it correct here.

Comment: @Barmar sorry! I think I managed to fix it now!

Comment: Could you supply some sample input?

Comment: Also, check my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393294/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-return-dictionary-delimiter-as-k/66414185#66414185, you might be able to reuse it to do what you want.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).